# ArrayList de classes

Tags: lista, arraylist

Tenho uma classe principal que tem como atributos classes auxiliares.

**Exemplo:** Classe principal `MoedasList`:

```
public class MoedasList {
    public USD USD;
    public USDT USDT;
    public ARS ARS;
}
```

Cada atributo é uma classe auxiliar com seus atributos individuais.

**Exemplo:** Classe auxiliar `USD`:

```
public class USD {
    public String code;           //": "BRL",
    public String codein;         //": "BRL",
    public String name;           //": "Dólar Comercial",
    public String high;           //": "3,9766",
    public String low;            //": "3,9748",
    public String varBid;         //": "0,0021",
    public String pctChange;      //: "0,05",
    public String bid;            //": "3,9765",
    public String ask;            //": "3,9767",
    public String timestamp;      //": "1557873008",
    public String create_date;    //": "2019-05-14 21:00:05"
}
```

Como eu monto um `ArrayList` da classe principal `MoedasList`?

Eu montei a classe dessa forma para receber os dados de um JSON.

Eu recebo os dados normais, mas agora gostaria de montar um `ArrayList`.

Comment: Amigo, está difícil saber o que você quer fazer. Tente explicar melhor sua necessidade por favor.

Comment: eu gostaria de retornar uma lista com todos os atributos da Classe MoedaList, sendo que os atritubos da Classe MoedaLis, sao todos Classes separadas com a especificaçao de cada moeda, com seus atributos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se a `ArrayList` é da classe `MoedasList`, você pode fazer

```
MoedasList[] moedas = new MoedasList[n];
```

onde `n` é o número de elementos da lista.

Em seguida, você precisa iniciar os objetos dessa classe.

```
moedas[0] = new MoedasList();
```

Caso queira iniciar todos os objetos da lista, você pode fazer

```
for (int i = 0; i < moedas.length; i++){
    moedas[i] = new MoedasList();
}
```

Comment: isso vou ter que iniciar todos os elementos, e mostrar em uma tela de entrada.  cada elemento iniciado, atributo, é uma classe de cada moeda especifica com seus atributos, tipo valor, etc.., entao, quando criar a list devera mostrar cada atributo da Classe MoedaList e tambem deve mostrar  os atributos valores, etc de cada moeda.

Comment: conequi acessar os atributos mas é um array bidimenssional